# How to stop logging for a specific user?

Tags: linux, logging, bash

I'm a root user on my server. There are a bunch of users on my system.
As you know, when you type `w` you can see who is and who isn't online. With the `last` command you can check last users who were logged in to your system, according to `/var/log/wtmp` path.

Is there any way to stop all logging throughout the system for a specific user?

I know we can do like `cat /dev/null > /var/log/wtmp`, but this action removes all of the logs.

It can be done by `rootkits` like `vlany`, but how we can do it without them, I mean with commands?

Comment: You would need to filter all log inputs through something that would block a certain user. You could rewrite the syslog process, but that only works for logs generated by syslog. If I wrote my own app, I could generate and store logs anywhere I like, for instance.

Comment: @schroeder, So we can not able to manage all log files as we want, even if we have root access ?

Comment: So what is the mechanism of vlany for instance ? It generates new syslog ?

Comment: Root access is not the problem. Knowing all the processes that log and knowing how/where they log is the problem.